# Can you spend extra mana on a spell that is not part of the casting cost?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Suppose I have a [Hall of the Bandit Lord](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHall%20of%20the%20Bandit%20Lord%5d) and a Plains out and I have a [Sacred Cat](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSacred%20Cat%5d) in hand. Is it possible to tap both lands while casting to give it haste, or can the hall only be used on creatures with a colorless mana cost (assuming no cost changing effects are active).

Likewise, is it possible to ignore cost reduction? For example, if I had a [Vizier of Remedies](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVizier%20of%20Remedies%5d) with [Oketra's Monument](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOketra%27s%5d%2b%5bMonument%5d) out, would it be possible to still pay the colorless mana to give it haste?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot overpay costs any more than you can underpay them. It's true that underpaying feels like "taking" an advantage (and thus unfair) while overpaying feels like "giving up" an advantage (and thus potentially fair), but the rules do not discriminate between the two: the way you pay a cost is by paying that cost, no more and no less. Similarly, you can't ignore cost reductions or other positive-seeming effects (like something that tells you to draw a card) any more than you can ignore cost increases or other negative-seeming effects (like something that damages you). Since almost nothing in Magic is good in *every* situation or bad in *every* situation, this is the really the most sensible, simple and consistent way the rules could be written.

[However there is one place that they *do* try to distinguish usually-good effects: if in competitive play you fail to notice that a bad triggered ability has triggered, it will probably get applied once it's noticed, but if you fail to notice a usually-good trigger (one of the ones on their list of ["lapsing"](http://www.gatheringmagic.com/melissadetora-062812-a-players-guide-to-triggered-abilities/) effects), it will not be applied later. *Purposefully* "forgetting" *any* kind of trigger is still cheating though - the *rules* do not distinguish between lapsing and non-lapsing triggers.]

Comment: Recommend qualifying 'costs' by narrowing to mana costs; there is a cost you can overpay, e.g. crewing a vehicle.

Comment: @drunkcynic Sort of. Crew 3 has a cost of "3 or more",  not a cost of 3 that you can overpay. So paying 4 isn't overpaying the cost, it's still paying "3 or more" which is the cost.

Comment: Also of note, if cost reductions are optional they mention it explicitly like Training Grounds does.